# SVN resolve multiple files using bash/terminal on OS X

Tags: svn, bash, macos

I have a lot of conflicts in a working copy that has been merged to, I know that each of them want to be resolved to the right side of the merge. Is it possible to do this in  bash/terminal on OSX, for example (in pseudo code:)

```
find . -name '*.merge-right.*'
   rm original-filename.filetype
   cp original-filename.filetype.merge-right.r123 original-filename.filetype
   svn resolved original-filename.filetype
```

I know the filetypes of all these files and they're all the same if that helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think svn [resolve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html) will do what you want:

```
svn resolve --accept --recursive base .
```

(or working, mine-full, theirs-full)

Comment: Thanks I was on SVN 1.4.4, didn't realise 1.5 had added the resolve command. I used --accept theirs-full for my requirement.